# Detect all Oracle versions installed

Tags: oracle, command-line, version, detect

How can I check all `oracle versions` and platforms that installed on `windows` machine from a `command line` or by`script` ?
Till now I was using `tnsping` and check for the output but it only show the first version according to the path environment variable.
Is there a way to get this info from the registry and without actually connect to `DB` ?

Answer (score 5):

Simplest method is to run command prompt and type sqlplus
it will show you the oracle version without actually logging into it.

Example: Run -> cmd

---

Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7601]
Copyright (c) 2009 Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

C:\Users\xyz>**sqlplus**

SQL*Plus: **Release 11.2.0.1.0 Production** on Wed Jan 1 16:46:40 2014

Copyright (c) 1982, 2010, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Enter user-name:

Comment: The problem is that it will show me only single version while the machine can have several installed, I'm creating a setup that should check if certain version is installed now in case there several version install I might not be able to find it.

Comment: Check this link, [Oracle Docs](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10501_01/em.920/a96697/moh.htm). They have mentioned registry entry   HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE -> Software -> Oracle -> ALL_HOMES, this seems to be useful.

Answer (score 2):

You'll want to query the **Oracle Inventory**.

For every Oracle installation, there is an entry in the "Oracle inventory". By default, the Oracle inventory is located under "C:\Program Files\Oracle\Inventory". However, this location can be changed.

In the Registry, the location of the Oracle inventory is in "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE/SOFTWARE/ORACLE", where you'll find the key "inst_loc". There, you'll find an XML file containing all installed versions (inventory.xml). [See the Oracle documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11857_01/em.111/e12255/oui2_manage_oracle_homes.htm#CHDEHFBJ) for an example.

Comment: +1 This is probably the best solution (short of using OEM agent target detection), but it still probably won't be very reliable.  In my experience, de-installing Oracle on Windows is very ugly.  Those locations very likely get over-looked, and may contain old versions that aren't really installed.

Answer (score 1):

Go here and open with Notepad:

- C:\Program Files (x86)\Oracle\Inventory\ContentsXML
- C:\Program Files\Oracle\Inventory\ContentsXML

Open File:
inventory.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes" ?>
<!-- Copyright (c) 1999, 2006, Oracle. All rights reserved. -->
<!-- Do not modify the contents of this file by hand. -->
<INVENTORY>
<VERSION_INFO>
   <SAVED_WITH>11.1.0.6.0</SAVED_WITH>
   <MINIMUM_VER>2.1.0.6.0</MINIMUM_VER>
</VERSION_INFO>
<HOME_LIST>
<HOME NAME="OraClient11g_home1" LOC="D:\Oracle\product\11.1.0\client_1" TYPE="O" IDX="1"/>
</HOME_LIST>
</INVENTORY>
```

Comment: Well,,, actually, the question was "command line or by script", I would advise to provide some sketch to that concept, is possible