# Get the Oracle Version using CMD

Tags: oracle, cmd

Is there is any command to find my installed ***oracle version*** from windows command prompt. (just like java -version..)

Comment: `wmic datafile where name^="c:\\windows\\notepad.exe" get version|findstr /i /v /c:"version"`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Detect all Oracle versions installed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20868030/detect-all-oracle-versions-installed)

Answer (score 0):

You need to locate ORACLE_HOME directory, to set it as environment variable and then to run  opatch:

```
set ORACLE_HOME=...
"ORACLE_HOME"\OPatch\opatch lspatches
```

This command lists the installed patches with the Oracle major version.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below to get the database version by navigating to the ORACLE_HOME directory

```
  $ORACLE_HOME\OPatch\opatch lsinventory | find "Oracle Database"
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, that *depends* on what you really have.

If you have installed Oracle onto your PC (such as my 11gXE), then you could try `sqlplus -v`:

```
c:\Temp>sqlplus -v

SQL*Plus: Release 11.2.0.2.0 Production
```

11.2.0.2.0; is that really so?

```
c:\Temp>sqlplus scott/tiger

SQL*Plus: Release 11.2.0.2.0 Production on Sri Svi 6 07:40:29 2020

Copyright (c) 1982, 2014, Oracle.  All rights reserved.


Connected to:
Oracle Database 11g Express Edition Release 11.2.0.2.0 - 64bit Production

SQL>
```

Yes, it is. I use SQL*Plus 11.2.0.2.0 which connects me to 11.2.0.2.0 database.

---

However, if I don't have Oracle installed on my PC but it is somewhere on database server and I access it via network, then it won't work because it'll display **SQL*Plus** (i.e. client installed on my PC), not **database** version. Besides, I can have several clients installed, so it depends on which `sqlplus` executable I ran.

Database version - in such a case - can't be retrieved from operating system command prompt only (at least, I don't know how to do it). You **can** obtain it by connecting to the database itself, e.g.

Client version:

```
M:\>sqlplus -v

SQL*Plus: Release 11.2.0.1.0 Production
```

ORCL database version is 11.2.0.4.0

```
M:\>sqlplus scott/tiger@orcl

SQL*Plus: Release 11.2.0.1.0 Production on Sri Svi 6 08:12:27 2020

Copyright (c) 1982, 2010, Oracle.  All rights reserved.


Connected to:
Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.4.0 - 64bit Production
With the Partitioning, Real Application Clusters, Automatic Storage Management, OLAP,
Data Mining and Real Application Testing options
```

ORCL2 database version is 10.2.0.5.0:

```
M:\>sqlplus scott/tiger@orcl2

SQL*Plus: Release 11.2.0.1.0 Production on Sri Svi 6 08:13:42 2020

Copyright (c) 1982, 2010, Oracle.  All rights reserved.


Connected to:
Oracle Database 10g Enterprise Edition Release 10.2.0.5.0 - 64bit Production
With the Partitioning, Real Application Clusters, Data Mining and Real Application Testing options

SQL>
```

---

When you're in SQL*Plus, query v$version, e.g.

```
SQL> select * From v$version where rownum = 1;

BANNER                                                                               CON_ID
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------- ----------
Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.2.0.1.0 - 64bit Production              0

SQL>
```

which shows that I'm currently connected to 12.2.0.1.0.

Comment: Thanks got the database version..!

Comment: You're welcome. It is custom here to accept and/or upvote answer(s) you find appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

This code allows you to display only the version of the database.

```
@echo off
set user_name=scott
set password=tiger
set net_service_name=edcu
set sql=select version from  PRODUCT_COMPONENT_VERSION where rownum=1;

(echo  conn %user_name%/%password%@%net_service_name% 
echo set heading off
echo %sql%
echo exit) |sqlplus -s  /nolog
```

For example output

```
D:\upwork\stackoverflow\get_version_oracle>get_oracle_version.bat
11.2.0.3.0
```